# Prevent two List properties from sharing any values

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two `List<int>`'s in my model, both of which are set with `<select multiple>` boxes. The possible values for these two dropdowns are identical, but I want to prevent the user from selecting `5` in the first one and also `5` in the second.

I need to either
1. Remove the matching value from the second select when it is chosen in the first (or vice versa)
2. Cause validation to fail if they share any values

1 is probably the better option, actually, which is why I've included the jQuery tag.

Here was my naive attempt at #2:

```
public class IntListOverlapAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    List<int> CompareList { get; set; }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        List<int> list;
        try
        {
            list = (List<int>)value;
        }
        catch
        {
            // Will only reach this point if both optional and empty, at which point we want validation to succeed
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        // If the lists have any common values
        if (list.Intersect(CompareList).Any())
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Select boxes cannot have matching data!");
        }
        else
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

That hinges on being able to have something like this:

```
[IntListOverlap(CompareList = List2)]
List<int> List1 { get; set; }
List<int> List2 { get; set; }
```

Which doesn't work.

Comment: Normally this kind of validation is not attached to the read only values, you would validate the _SelectedValue_ property.

Comment: I would do this validation only at the end when the user submits the form using javascript. Because there is a circular dependency, if you do it during selection, things become messy: user selects 5, remove 5 from 2nd, user selects 2 from 2nd, remove add 5 back and remove 2 from 2nd and so on (I don't like it).

Comment: @maccettura I'm sorry, can you elaborate? I'm new to this.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Good point... As far as I know, the only way to do this is with a ton of JavaScript loops to keep track of which value was changed, remove the old one, or insert the new one.

Comment: no it does not need ton of javascript. Do not even remove any items. Simply check if the 2 selected items are the same and tell the user they cannot do that.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yeah, but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: @Sinjai why wouldn't you want to solve your problem in a practical and time efficient way? Why include the jquery tag at all?

Comment: @lloyd I want to solve my problem in the way most attractive to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
@foreach(var item in list1)
{
    <select multiple id="select_id">
        <option value="@item">foo</option>
    <select>
}

@foreach(var item in list2)
{
    <select multiple id="select_id">
        <option value="@item">bar</option>
    <select>
}

<script>
    $("#validationbutton).click()
    {
        $("#select_id option:selected").each(function(){
            //......
        }
    }
</script>
```